# Ajax request shows JSON after success

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to do a simple login through `AJAX` and it works fine except that after the success callback alerts the response, the browser shows the `JSON` response like this:

> {"status":"success","username":1234}

I have used the same piece of code several times before with no problems, but I think I am missing some knowledge as to why this is happening? There are some modifications of course, but the `AJAX` part is the same in both `PHP` and `Jquery` and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is the Jquery:

```
$('#btnLogin').on('click', function(){
   login();
});

function login(){
var un = $('#loginUn').val();
var pwd = $('#loginPwd').val();

 $.ajax({
     url: 'index.php?page=login', 
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {'un': un, 'pwd': pwd},
     success: function(data){
            alert("You are logged in as "+data.username);
     },
     error: function (request, error, data) {
        console.log(arguments);
        alert(" Can't do because: " + error+ " DATA: " + data);
    }
 });
```

}

The PHP controller:

```
include_once 'models/login.class.php';
$user = new Login( $dbh );


// If the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['un'])){

    // Check if fields are empty
    $fields = array('un', 'pwd');

    $error = false; //No errors yet

    //Loop trough each field
    foreach($fields AS $fieldname) { 
        if(!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || empty($_POST[$fieldname])) {
        $error = true; //Yup there are errors
        }
    }
    // If there are no errors
    if(!$error) { 
        $un     = $_POST['un'];
        $pwd    = $_POST['pwd'];

        $user->checkUser($un, $pwd );
    }   
}   
$view = include_once"views/login-html.php"; 
return $view;
```

And finally the model generating the response:

```
class Login {
private $dbh;

// Connect to database
public function __construct ( $pdo ) {
    $this->dbh = $pdo;
}

public function checkUser ($un, $pwd ){
    $sth = $this->dbh->prepare('SELECT password, username FROM employees WHERE username = ?');

    $sth->execute(array($un));

    //Getting the data from db
    while($r=$sth->fetch()){
            $password   = $r['password'];
            $username   = $r['username'];
    }

    if($un == $username && $pwd == $password){

        $array = array('status' => 'success', 'username' => $username);
        // echo "<script>alert('You are logged in as ".$username."');</script>";
        // echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
        // echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'username' => $username);
        $forEcho = json_encode($array);

        echo $forEcho;          
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'failure'));
    }
    exit;
}// End checkUser function
}// End of class
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
        <h1>Login</h1>

         <form role="form" method="post">

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <h3>Username</h3>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" name="un" class="form-control" id="loginUn" placeholder="Please type in your username">
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <h3 id="lblPassword">Password</h3>
                    <div class="input-group"> 
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="fa fa-key"></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="password" name="pwd" class="form-control" id="loginPwd" placeholder="Please type in your password">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button id="btnLogin" type="¨button" name="btnLogin" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

If somebody could tell me where I am going wrong I would really appreciate it! Have been looking for a solution/explanation with no result for several hours.

EDIT: Added the HTML. The alert in the success callback works just fine, but when closing it the JSON is all that is displayed on a blank screen. Never had this happen to me before.

Comment: I suspect the problem lies, partially, in the HTML which you haven't shared.

Comment: you are returning the `$view = include_once"views/login-html.php";`. which is a file.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter no, not if you use `dataType: 'json'` in your `$.ajax` function. jQuery does this all for you.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter dataType:'json' works as JSON.parse , so op don't have a need to use it

Comment: ...`$response['status'] = 'ok'; $response['username'] = $username; else $response['status'] = 'failure';` and after if else statement that just do `echo json_encode($response);`

Comment: @Manchary Manchaary this is better practice, but the result is the same. Does what ever in the success callback and I can access the data, but still goes to a new page and echoes the JSON.

Comment: Since you have got your inputs wrapped into a `<form>` tag, you should post it not on button `click()`, try instead doing this `$('#my_form').submit(function(){   login(); return false;  });` The page is reloaded because of the `<form>` tag; dont forget to add an `id` to your `<form>`; Also is it necessary to declare `type` for a button? I don't thnik so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an invalid value for the type attribute:

```
type="¨button"
```

… so the button reverts to the default and is a submit button.

You are seeing the results of submitting the form normally instead of using Ajax.

As a short term fix, remove the `¨`. In the long term, you should adopt [unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) as a best practise.

Comment: That was embarrassing :/ You are totally right. Even checked the HTML in a validator, but I had accidentally set the type as submit ( as the answer below suggested ) and never checked the HTML after I caught that stupid error. Thank your for your keen eye!

Comment: @MaDaHoPe also **notice:** in the first version(s) of your question you did not include your HTML - and that's exactly where the problem was hiding.

Answer (score 0):

I bet `btnLogin` is a submit button, huh.. return false or prevent default to prevent the form from submitting..

```
$('#btnLogin').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    login();
});
```

Comment: Nope, the form is submitting and it goes to the success callback, but then it shows the returned JSON.